# For $n \geq 2$, there is no $\phi : S^n \to S^1$ such that $\phi(-x) = -\phi(x)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Show that for $n\geq 2$ there is not any function $\phi: S^n \rightarrow S^1$ such that $\phi(-x)=-\phi(x)$.

I have no idea about how to solve this problem. It is quite similar to Borsuk-Ulam Theorem.

Any hint?

Thanks for help!

Comment: For the second part, show that no map $\phi:S^n\to S^1$ can be surjective via inclusion of fundamental groups. The result follows.

Comment: Via inclusion? what do you mean? It is clear that the induced homomorphism is the trivial one.

Comment: Yes. If a map was surjective, it would be possible to include a path from $S^n$ to $S^1$ which is nontrivial. This is clearly not possible, so such a map does not exist.

Comment: Why surjective maps induced non trivial homorphisms?

Comment: @AlexS there certainly are surjective maps from any sphere  to any sphere of lower dimension (also of higher dimension, but that involves space filling maps). It just happens that ones from higher dimensional spheres into a circle are nulhomotopic.

Comment: Yes, sorry. You are absolutely right. I'm getting some concepts confused.

Comment: @YotasTrejos How about this? Suppose there exists such a map $\phi$. Then let $\gamma$ be a path on $S^n$ such that for each $x\in\gamma$, $-x\in \gamma$. Then for each $y\in \phi(\gamma$), $-y\in\phi(\gamma)$, so $\phi$ takes $\gamma$ to a nontrivial path in $S^1$.

Comment: That's very useful. Thanks!

Comment: I have a doubt, how can I assure that the path it is non trivial?

Answer (score 0):

The Borsuk-Ulam Theorem states that for any continuous odd function $f : S^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, there is $p \in S^n$ such that $f(p) = 0$.

If such a map $\phi$ existed, then $f = i\circ\phi$ would be a continuous odd map $S^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (here $i$ denotes the inclusion $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^n$). By Borsuk-Ulam, there is $p \in S^n$ such that $f(p) = 0$, but $f(p) = i(\phi(p)) = \phi(p) \neq 0$ as $\phi(p) \in S^1$. Therefore there is no such map $\phi$.